# Translation of PHP example code from mysqli to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

I hope that someone would be willing to help me out here - since I know it shouldn't be too hard.

I found and tutorial example of something that I wish to do. Unfortunately the sample code make use of the old MYSQLi and I have no idea how to go about to change it over to PDO.

[Here is a link to the full tutorial](http://www.webslesson.info/2016/11/php-ajax-jquery-load-dynamic-content-in-bootstrap-popover.html)

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Then further down:

```
       <div class="container" style="width:800px;">  
            <h2 align="center">PHP AJAX Jquery - Load Dynamic Content in Bootstrap Popover</h2>  
            <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>                 
            <br /><br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="20%">ID</th>  
                           <th width="80%">Name</th>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><a href="#" class="hover" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a></td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
       </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplciate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157024/how-to-convert-pdo-to-mysqli

Comment: And when was mysqli referred to as old??  Maybe I didn't get the memo

Comment: - That Possible duplicate is a reversed role of what I want. That is PDO to mysqli
- I want mysqli to PDO.

Thanks

Comment: @Wojtek T... My bad! I confused it with its predecessor mysql... mysqli is in fact its replacement but I prefer getting used to PDO since MySQLi only support drivers for MySQL DB as apposed to PDO that offer support drivers for multiple databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would do this query in PDO

**database connection:**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset={$charset}";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Notice we set some extra parameters here, namely `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, which makes allows PDO to do proper prepared statements instead of emulated ones, which makes it safer. (If we didn't do this, it would basically be just as safe as string concatenation) Note, in your query you wrote, this actually doesn't matter much as there is nothing to prepare, but it will be useful later when you have some statements that needs data to be passed.

**Query:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id desc")->fetchAll();
```

**Loop:**

```
if(!empty($stmt)) {
    foreach($stmt as $row) {  
        ?>  
            <tr>  
               <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>  
               <td><a href="#" class="hover" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a></td>  
            </tr>
        <?
    }
} else {
    //show error, no results
}
```

---

I would like to mention that the `MySQLi_*` interface is not really "old", it's not deprecated or unused by far. I prefer PDO over MySQLi because it seems easier to me, but both syntax's are fully valid and supported. The problem arises when you are not using [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) using either interface.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the array from the query is not empty.  Because if it's empty, it'll throw errors

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thanks so much! Using your code I got it to output 1 2 8 which is the three entries I have in the DB.

Comment: Awesome @francoiscx! And thanks to you, I just passed 2k rep ^.^ Cheers!

Comment: @francoiscx If you're interested, I wrote a function to make PDO queries really easy to do, you can [check that out here](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function). It's basically just a wrapper function that you pass the query and the values and it automatically does the proper procedure.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  - Cheers to your 2k rep! And thanks for the additional info. I will check into it in the morning when the brain is fresh.